# Add a boxed text with the same theme in beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to add a slide with only a subtitle which is inside a box of the same style as the current beamer style. Here is a picture of what I want. The second page is what I want (I Photoshop it, of course).

Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}

\title{This is the main title}
\author{Patrick Li}
\institute{StackExchange.com}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

% Here should be the code to produce the second page in the above picture.

\end{document}
```

Comment: To produce a box similar to this, have a look at the [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possible answers:

1. by using `\partpage`
2. by using `\titlepage`
3. by mimicking the theme's template.

## Using `\partpage`

If your aim is to generate a frame announcing the part's title you can use the `\partpage` command. To install such a command every time a part is created just write in your preamble

```
\AtBeginPart{\frame{\partpage}}
```

The contents of the part page are controlled by the `part page` template that you can modify with `\setbeamertemplate{part page}{<contents>}`.

## Using `\titlepage`

If you want to generate a title page with different title, subtitle etc just set the new values and call `\titlepage`

```
\begin{frame}
    \title{Part I}\author{}\date{}\institute{}\subtitle{}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Even better, if you are using this to print the part's title you can use

```
\title{\insertpart}
```

and if you want `beamer` to generate such frame at each part you can pass the commands to `\AtBeginPart` in your preamble as in

```
\AtBeginPart{
    \begin{frame}
        \title{\insertpart}\author{}\date{}\institute{}\subtitle{}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
}
```

## Mimicking the theme

Suppose you are using the default theme.
The definition of the title page element is in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` and contains the following snippet to generate the blue box:

```
\begin{centering}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
      \vskip0.25em%
      {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
    \fi%     
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  ...
\end{centering}
```

so you can just put a `beamercolorbox` in your frame as in

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
    Part I
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

However you will need to change the parameters to match your theme's design.